# Parse an array of bytes by delimiter character/byte to obtain the first token only

Tags: arrays, c, linux, string, char

I did an example of using `strtok()` not with null-terminated string just for the general purpose of **obtaining only the first token** by delimiter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
     int a = 0x44434241;
     char *pt = strtok ((void *)&a, "C");
     printf("%s\n", pt);

     return 0;
}
```

It works well and printf `AB`.
Does this is the proper way to parse an array of bytes by delimiter to obtain only the first token? Or this should be done somehow different?

**UPD**:
By the way I didn't find any information in the [`strtok()` manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) that null-terminated string or C-string should be passed there.

Comment: `str` isn't pointing to a null-terminated string. You can't use it as such. All you have accomplished with the shown code is to have *undefined behavior*. That it seemingly work is just unfortunate.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is, there is no ready-made function to achieve the goal? Do I have to do it by-hand?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? If you have an underlying problem then please ask about that directly instead. Otherwise your question just becomes an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If it's plain curiosity then that's fine, but please tell us that in the question itself.

Comment: So what do you think happens when it doesn't find the delimiter?

Comment: Another problem with your example is that it's not portable due to endianness. Your code will print `AB` on little-endian machines, and `D` on big-endian machines.

Comment: @user3386109 Endianness doesn't matter. I have text file, but read it through mmap. So there is no null-terminated strings, just a big array of characters

Comment: `strtok` only returns the first token if you call it only once. It does not have anything to do with the string being null terminated or not. I think this is the confusion if I understood correctly your question.

Comment: @Dmitri Seems that this is the main problem, why we can't call `strtok()` not with null-terminated string. But is there any other way?

Comment: Why are you reading a text file into a byte array, and not terminate it as a string? What are you really doing? Why do you need to get "tokens" out of this byte array? How difficult would it be to allocate just one extra byte and set it to the string null-terminator?

Comment: Not bad... Using a "string" function but not using a C "string". And, limiting yourself to psuedo-strings that are only a 1-2 bytes long (presuming 'endian' problems don't make it completely wrong... What is the point of writing brain-damaged code that will fail (causing UB) far more than it succeeds? If strtok doesn't find your "C", it will wander off into memory looking for one... (And, when if finds one, it will set that byte to '\0'... Just plain dumb...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I need a very fast search through the CSV file, so I decided to do it with `mmap()` instead of `read()`/`fread()`. To get rid of the overhead.

Comment: @Fe2O3 memchr will give me an address of delimiter, but I also need to form string from the beginning of string till the delimiter. Then I need to do strcmp with some other reference string

Comment: @Fe2O3 Actually, I'm not writing such a bad code anywhere yet. That's why I asked the question, it seemed to me that this was a bad idea with strtok. But I didn't come up with how else to implement it easy way

Comment: Once you have the delimiter, `memcpy` from the beginning to the delimiter into another array. Or use `memcmp` with the mmapped file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is, I need to do it by-hand. Okay, thanks. I thought maybe there already exists some kind of API to solve such a strange problem

Comment: Regarding the overhead of reading the file into your own buffers, have you *measured* it? With an optimized build, of course. Is it really that bad, is it really one of the top-two bottlenecks in your program? Considering the other work that needs to be done to make the memory mapped file handling work properly, how much do you really save?

Comment: Also, all this about the memory mapped file and your want (so far I don't see it as a *need*) to parse it, that should have been part of the question itself. That is the actual problem you want to solve, and the problem you should have asked about directly.

Answer (score 1):

The buffer being searched by `strtok()` is not a string. Expect undefined behaviour and lots of crashes.

The entire thing could be *hand crafted* but it is sometimes useful to engage standard library functions. `memchr()` is used to find one byte among many.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char haystack[] = "ne edlehayhaaysneehayedlenedlehayneedehayneeFOOneedleBARgibbleflapborpne edle";
    size_t sz = sizeof haystack - 1; // excluding '\0'

    char srch[] = "needle";
    size_t szSrch = sizeof srch - 1; // excluding '\0'

    // for some reason, OP wants to find LAST char, then check for 'token'
    char c = srch[szSrch-1];

    for( char *p = haystack; (p = (char*)memchr( p, c, sz - (p-haystack) ) ) != NULL; p++ ) {
        char *q = p-szSrch+1;
        if( q >= haystack && memcmp( q, srch, szSrch ) == 0 ) {
            printf( "Found: %.*s\n", szSrch, q );
            printf( "Context: %.*s\n", szSrch+6, ( q-3<haystack ) ? haystack : q-3 );
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Found: needle
Context: FOOneedleBAR
```

Comment: As I mentioned in comments, I need to parse CSV file. So the first token is the first column, i.e. string before `;`. I understand that this was not obvious from my question. Also strcmp is needed as I mentioned. Just to check if the reference string is before of after in sorted CSV. Bad question, sorry

Comment: @budoattack Just so you know, `strtok()` succeeds by replacing the 'separator character' with a '\0'... Once that is done, your large collection of bytes ( from a CSV) will be terminated at that location. The next invocation of any strxxx() function won't be able to get beyond that '\0'... Do you really want "destructive" searching of the data? Maybe you want to take a close look at the code above... It is non-destructive.... (Thx for the UV, btw...)

Comment: This is read-only mmap and I just need to obtain first column. And I need to compare strings to figure out which is greater. So how can I easy do it with memcmp?

Comment: @budoattack So, the code presented in this question has nothing to do with what you are trying to achieve... Why not try asking a (new) question wherein you clearly spell-out what you have (data) and what you are trying to achieve... What's the point of asking for "guesses" that don't suit your needs.